# iPhone adding blur effect to image

Tags: iphone, uiimage, blur

I have browsed stack for this so common issue, and have found that there is no default function to add blur effect to UIImage, and in order to make it one would have to manipulate individual pixels... I presume there are many advanced users who have tried and accomplished this. Does anyone have code to this, or some really specific pointers how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an iOS image filter library which you could possibly use.

https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters

Answer (score 1):

an other one could be this: [Filtrr for iOS](https://github.com/OmidH/Filtrr)